# Overflow:hidden for images

Tags: html, css

I have 6 images that devide into 2 rows, 3 columns (each row has 3 images) that display in the large screen. When I turn into a small screen I want every row to get 1 image, but I just want to show 4 images, others will be hidden. How can I do it by css? Thank you.

Comment: Show your effort so far what you did.

Comment: search for responsive websites, css media queries, then experiment with it and get back to us once you're stuck.

Comment: I try to use display:none when display in the small screen. Images are hidden but the spaces contain the images are still remain

Comment: `display: none` should hide images as expected: you've got another problem then (using width and height for example but I can't see any code / problem reproduced here so it's only a guess)

Comment: Use bootstrap grid to split as per your screeen size.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap 4 [visibility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/):

```css
[class*="col-"] {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.images img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container images">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 d-none d-md-block"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 d-none d-md-block"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```